# Error after modifying sources.list

Tags: linux, apt-get

I modified sources.list and now it wont load. I took everything out except for the first line and it still errors out. Any ideas based on it's output?

sources.list:

> deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main

Output:

> Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty InRelease
>
> Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg
>
> Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty Release
>
> Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main TranslationIndex
>
> Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted TranslationIndex
>
> Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main i386 Packages
>
> 404  Not Found
>
> Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted i386 Packages
>
> 404  Not Found
>
> Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en_US
>
> Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en
>
> Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Translation-en_US
>
> Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Translation-en
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   404   Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages
>   404  Not Found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sources.list generator at [repogen](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) looks to be a good way to get a customized sources file. Try using that to get a feel for the syntax and content of the file.

A proxy could be configured such that it wouldn't let you access the server. To fix this you must open `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and change or remove `Acquire::http::Proxy`